# Allow anonymous S3 access via CloudFront and aws cli but not via rest endpoint in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking to have a publicly readable S3 bucket that is accessible via a CloudFront and via the s3 cli or boto3 or other scripting source, but not have `https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` accessible via a browser  (I'm worried about users being confused if they use that and get xml listings or don't get the appropriate pages that our Lambda@Edge is injecting)

Is there something I can add to the bucket policy to ensure that access isn't via a browser accessing the `https://my-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` endpoint?

This is an excerpt of my bucket policy

```
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3ListObjectsOAI",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity RANDOMSTRING"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3GetObjectsOAI",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity RANDOMSTRING"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        }
```

Comment: Remove `PublicRead` and `PublicList`. You have an explicit grant to cloudfront so you do no need public at all.

Comment: Thank you.
I want users to be able to list and read via aws cli though.
`aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name --no-sign-request`

Comment: Anonymously????

Comment: Yes. This is data that is intentionally being made publicly readable (not writable).  It is currently available via https and we want to expand the available methods of access.